# Network failure during git fetch command

Tags: git, git-fetch

I'm trying to investigate what happens if the network would fail during a git fetch command.
I can't find any documentation that really goes into detail of the fetch command and digging into the git C source code seems a bit overwhelming. Where can I find some good detailed description what fetch really does?

I'm investigating the possibility of using git as a backup solution for binary files. If the network goes down in the middle of a fetch, will git clean up and remove the downloaded data objects? Or will they just be left in the .git folder?

Comment: From my experience, it does _not_ hold any of the information that was downloaded so it starts from scratch.

Comment: I guess it does not clean up the downloaded data objects because that would just mean it has to download them the next time again. They will most likely stay in their orphaned state and in case no fetch happens again, they will eventually be cleaned up by the `git gc` command. But that is just how I would implement fetching, not necessarily how it is actually done.

Comment: Git makes for terrible *backup* software, for reasons I allude to in [Chapter 1](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf). Any software that is good at version control is bad at backups, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "kinds" of transports used for both fetch and push:

- the "dumb" one sends entire objects;
- the "smart" one sends a *thin pack*.

Smart transports are generally far more efficient, so most Git transfers use the smart method.

When using the smart method, `git fetch` will bring over a single thin pack, and then "fatten" the thin pack to become a normal pack.  This pack is then just like any other pack, and resides in `.git/objects/pack/` as usual.  If the connection dies before the pack is fully received, the received thin pack must be (and is) deleted and nothing remains: the next `git fetch` starts over, generating a new and quite possibly entirely different thin pack (it may be compressed against different base objects).

When using a dumb transport, however, `git fetch` *could* opt to store each object as soon as it is complete.  Whether it does so, I have no idea.

Note that `git push` in particular uses what Git calls a *quarantine area* for new incoming objects.  Objects are placed "in quarantine" until the pre-receive and update hooks have run, and are migrated to the repository's object database only if they're wanted.  (This particular optimization came from the GitHub folks, who didn't want to keep multi-gigabyte objects that got rejected as being too large.  GitHub already keep every object forever, so this was obviously *awful* for them, before the idea of quarantining.)  Hence even with a dumb transport, a push that fails partway through would have to start over.

The `fetch` operation has no reason to bother with quarantine and presumably doesn't do so.